# subtracting some of the data within a data frame by an id

Tags: r

Similar to my previous question but more complicated.

```
date <- c("2016-03-24", "2016-03-24", "2016-03-24", "2016-03-24", "2016-03-24",
          "2016-03-24", "2016-03-24", "2016-03-24", "2016-03-24", "2016-03-24")
location <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, "out", "out")
sensor <- c(1, 16, 1, 16, 1, 16, 1, 16, 1, 16)
Temp <- c(35, 34, 92, 42, 21, 47, 37, 42, 63, 12)
df <- data.frame(date, location, sensor, Temp)
```

I want to subtract location `"out"` from location `"4"` ignoring the other locations and I want to do it by date and sensor. I tried the code below but got NAs as the result. I am not sure what I did wrong.

```
DailyMaxInOutDiff04 <- df %>% 
  group_by(date, sensor) %>% 
  summarise(diff = Temp[location == "4"] - Temp[location == "out"])
```

**Edit** This example is now working, but it is not working with my actual data frame.

The result I would like is the following:

```
        date location sensor diff
1 2016-03-24        4      1  -26
2 2016-03-24        4     16   30
```

Comment: Don't do `as.data.frame` with `cbind`; you're coercing all your data to character by making a matrix before you make a data.frame. Just use `data.frame` by itself and the `NA`s go away.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks. That works for this example, but it doesn't work for my real data frame (where I don't use `cbind` and `as.data.frame`), but it still produces NAs. Could it be because date and location are characters in my data frame where as they are factors in the example data frame?

Comment: It only really matters if a given operation won't work with that type. `group_by` doesn't care, and `==` should be fine, so apparently it's something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to a `filter` first before we do the grouping

```
df %>%
    filter(location %in% c(4, 'out')) %>% 
    group_by(date, sensor) %>% 
    summarise(Diff = Temp[location=="4"] - Temp[location=="out"],
              location = first(location)) %>%
    select(1, 2, 4, 3) 
#       date sensor location  Diff
#      <fctr>  <dbl>   <fctr> <dbl>
#1 2016-03-24      1        4   -26
#2 2016-03-24     16        4    30
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand everything except the select function. Why 1, 2, 4, 3?

Comment: @phaser It is just to keep the columns in the same order as in your expected output.  These are the column indexes